# Cloning a repo with HTTP URL

Tags: git, apache, http, cloning

I want to clone a git repo with http URL. I'm using apache webserver for this. I'm able to clone the repo but it appears to be a empty repository. But what i'm expecting is to get all the files in the repo.

I have created two new directories named as "git" and also "codebase" in apache2 document root and copied all the files from bitbucket repository to the directory i created(codebase) including the .git folder and files. Created authentication for the folder which i created because i want to restrict public access. After all this when i'm trying to do git clone http://server_name(or)IP/git/codebase/ this is appears to be cloned empty repository

I want to get all the files whenever i do git clone with http URL. http://server_name(or)IP/git/codebase/

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand: do you want to clone an existing repo *from* bitbucket, or you want to send a repo that you have on your server/machine *to* bitbucket?

Comment: I want to configure git in a machine and want to create a repo and  than clone the repo using HTTP URL using servername or IP address. Let me explain you what i'm trying to do and why.

Comment: So I would say: first you should create the directory you want, and initiate it as a repo with a simple `git init` command from inside of it. That way git knows that's something it needs to follow. You customize it as it serves you (e.g. create your .gitignore file), you add your files, create the first commit, and *only then* you send the repo to bitbucket, github, gitlab, or whatever cloud git service you use.

Comment: Please check below links for reference and it describes what i'm trying to achieve. 
https://gitirc.eu/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.html
https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Setup_git_over_HTTP_server

Comment: @GiampaoloFerradini thanks for sharing the following link
https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Setup_git_over_HTTP_server
This is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can now clone public repositories hosted on GitHub over HTTP. This is very slow and should only be used if the git port (9418) is blocked due to a firewall or other tomfoolery.

Try it out:

git clone http://github.com/defunkt/facebox.git

If you’re a Ruby on Rails user, you can now install plugins without Git installed on your machine. This means your loyal blog readers stuck in the past don’t need Git to benefit from your Ruby wizardry.

Try it out:

./script/plugin install http://github.com/defunkt/cache_fu.git

Comment: GitHub supported http cloning since 2008 - https://github.blog/2008-06-19-http-cloning/